# tsql for getting a user's permissions without impersonation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, audit

Is there a check I can make to see if a user has modify rights to any object on the *server* without running the query as that user?

I need to create a logon audit report that lists logon times for accounts that have insert/update access for something on the server(i.e. on any database on the server)

This also needs to not impact performance(if possible) or have the smallest impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this article](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/in-sql-server-2005-how-do-i-display-all-permissions-a-userlogin-has-is-there-a-stored-procedure-to-do-this/):

```
select sys.schemas.name 'Schema', sys.objects.name Object, sys.database_principals.name username, sys.database_permissions.type permissions_type,
     sys.database_permissions.permission_name, 
     sys.database_permissions.state permission_state,
     sys.database_permissions.state_desc,
     state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AS
 from sys.database_permissions
 join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id = 
     sys.objects.object_id
 join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
 join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id = 
     sys.database_principals.principal_id
 order by 1, 2, 3, 5
```

You would want to filter by `username`. And keep in mind this shows only the explicitly defined permissions (and deny rules), not effective permissions.

Comment: Any way to pull effective permissions?

Comment: It would be a combination of this as well as whatever rights are granted through groups, schemas, and so on. I don't know of anything out of the box that provides that. Hopefully this is a decent starting point for you though.